# Want to create Layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator, android-widget

I want to create a layout something like shown in image below can anyone please tell me what is this component shown over xml layout and how to us it.

[image]

Comment: If you have the apk file with this layout, I can help you to disassemble it and get the actual code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement [Sliding Drawer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SlidingDrawer.html) in Android..

Comment: I think this is not Sliding Drawer, b,coz it is automatically appears when user click on Change Background Button. Is there is any way that we can implement Sliding Drawer with such Functionality.

Comment: @KrishnakantDalal yes i think you can open/close this sliding drawer based on the button click.

Comment: He he ! Trying to copy components from Apple :D - Sliding Drawer is nice Tool. Thx for that.

Comment: @Spark Still Android rocks :D

Comment: @Spark that we don't know. My brother Whether Android or iPhone gets rock....aapne su? they are not going to give us small bucks

Comment: I found this is a Popup window now I am trying to implement it in my application.